# Creating a major upgrade for a product

Tags: installshield, installshield-2015

I'm using installshield Professional 2015 . I need to make an upgrade for a product whose installation directory , registry path and company ID has got changed  in the latest version of it.

Install shield detects that there is an older version installed and goes for upgrade . but the upgrade fails with message "installation is interrupted".

is it possible for upgrading the product without loss of any data (retaining the data of previous version and upgrading successfully)?

If it is possible , is it enough to create a new major upgrade path under upgrade paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL which is called during major upgrade process, returns false or sets a flag to false condition, which was causing the installation to fail.

Solving the issues in the dll file, makes this installation successful.